# Unknown device in boot loader

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bios

When I open the boot menu of my motherboard(x570 aorus elite). I get to see my nvme SSd(Samsung SSD 970 EVO 1TB) and the windows bootmanager is correct. But I also see third option for Ubuntu on the same SSD. I don't understand stand where the third option is coming from and how to delete it. If I try to boot from it it says the device is not bootable.

Picture 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amKJ8.jpg)

Comment: UEFI boot entries are stored in NVRAM. Did you ever have Ubuntu installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that days before you installed Ubuntu and it's still in your boot menu, you can edit this menu from windows by System Configuration (use msconfig in Run) or use other 3rd party programs like EasyBCD. Good luck